# Is it possible to save userinput on a webstite to a txt file?

Tags: html, save

I am trying to make a website where the user enters something which then should be saved on a txt file, i tried it with js code which i found but its not working. I dont really know how to do it, this is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form onsubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="pwd" id ="pwd"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
  function WriteToFile(passForm) {
  set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
  set s   = fso.CreateTextFile("data.txt", True);
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var pwd  = document.getElementById('pwd');
  s.writeline("Username :" + name);
  s.writeline("Password :" + pwd);
  s.writeline("-----------------------------");
  s.Close();
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with pure HTML and JavaScript as JavaScript doesn't have access to server files.
You have to do some server side programming to achieve the same.

For example in PHP, you may use `fwrite()`. For more details, refer to the official documentation of server side language you use.